# Find expected value of X

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a problem with following task. We have a square with sided equal to 1. We now slice it with two lines horizontal and vertical. Now let $Z$ be the minimal area of the $4$ rectangles. I need to calculate $E Z$. So my idea was $Z=\min{(xy,(1-x)y,(1-y)x,(1-x)(1-y)})$ and calculate distribution:
$$P(Z<t)$$
Is my approach right?

Comment: Note that $Z$ may also be written as $\min(x, 1-x)\cdot \min(y, 1-y)$. That might help.

Comment: The lines are independent, so the expected value of the area is equal to the product of the expected values of ...

Comment: What are the distributions of the random variables ? Are they uniformly distributed ?

Comment: @kludg area will be smallest when $x\in (0,0.5)$ and $y\in (0,0.5)$  so $EX=0.25$  and $E Y=0.25$. And $E Z = 0.25\cdot 0.25$ and three other cases when $0.5 <x <1$ and $0 <y <0.5$ and so on? Callculus, it's a square so they should be ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$ W = \begin{cases} x & 0\leq x \leq 0.5 \\ 1-x & 0.5 \lt x \end{cases} $$ then $W$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,0.5]$. This can be shown by $$ P(W<t) = P(x<t)+P(x>1-t) = 2t \hspace{10pt} , \hspace{10pt}  0 \leq t \leq 0.5 $$ Defining $H$ on $y$ in a similar manner , then $H$ is also uniformly distributed over $[0,0.5]$

Then $$ E[Z] = E[H]E[W] $$